# Specified cast is not valid exception in ms access query using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

hey guys m having this wierd exception of cast though my datatypes are correct in db:

```
string sql =
            string.Format(
                @"select aim_network_id,aim_network_name,oxinetwork_id,pack_id,pack_name,p_face_value,pm_prefix from Operator where aim_network_id='{0}'",
                gridbackOffice["aim_network_id", gridbackOffice.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value);
        OleDbCommand getSelectedGridDatecmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = getSelectedGridDatecmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtAimNetworkID.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            txtAimNetworkName.Text = reader.GetString(1);
            txtPARNetworkID.Text = reader.GetString(2);
            txtPARFaceValue.Text = reader["p_face_value"].ToString();
           //in above line if i'm doing this `reader.GetString(5)` then i'm getting specified cast exception and that to randomly i.e some time it works fine and suddenly sometime gives this exception
            txtPARPackID.Text = reader.GetString(3);
            txtPARPackName.Text = reader.GetString(4);
            txtPARPMPrefix.Text = reader["pm_prefix"].ToString();
        }
```

I'm little bit confused if m using this `reader["p_face_value"].ToString()` then my code is running very smoothly but whats the issue with using this `reader.GetString(5)` , according to me both method return string, nebody had faced this error b4 ?
....Error is at 4th and 7th line in while loop.

**Exception**:Specified cast is not valid (InvalidCastException unhandled)

Comment: Post complete `Exception` details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, [OleDbDataReader.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) does not perform any conversions before attempting to cast to a string - therefore the data retrieved must *already* be a string.

**If there is a chance that the value in that column could be null**, the docs suggest that you should [check if the value is null first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

```
if (  !reader.IsDBNull(5) ) {
    txtPARFaceValue.Text = reader.GetString(5); 
}
```

Calling `reader["p_face_value"]` on a null value returns [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) - and when you call [ToString() on DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.dbnull.tostring%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), you get an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring.aspx):

> No conversions are performed;
>   therefore the data retrieved must
>   already be a string.

If the column is not a string type, you'll need to use the `.ToString()` method to convert it.

Comment: but how come it is running on first time, i mean it does works for a while but then suddenly that exception appears

Comment: It fails when it encounters a null value in your data, @FosterZ - see my answer for how to stop it from happening.

Comment: @Dexter: yes man, this db was containing some null values in p_face_value.. my laziness i nvr look'd into the db...thnx

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of p_face_value in your database?

Based on the error description given it seems that this is not a string type, so when you call:

```
reader.GetString(5)
```

the code errors out as it cannot convert whatever type it is to a string.  The .ToString() method will work as this does not use a cast.

Comment: p_face_value is String i.e Text in ms access

Answer (score 0):

You should use GetString only when the column is a string-equivalent type in the database (like varchar), in your case "p_face_value" seems to be a numeric type, therefore it cannot simply convert it to a string.

The way you're doing it right now is the right way.

Comment: but my p_face_value is string in db...i said it is working fine while fetchin' data...but sometime suddenly it gets error..